# OpenCart - finding files

Tags: opencart2.x

I am relatively new to OpenCart and need help locating the right files on Cpanel to customize site, most especially the home page.  How do I locate a file name using Google Chrome Inspect element on storefront and then find the same file on my Cpanel File Manager? I am most especially looking for the html file on file manager for the home page.  I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you the correct way.

Lets say your store URL is

```
http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=common/home
```

There are two parameters after route. They are

1st is folder
2nd is file
3rd is function

Since we know that this is the front end, so we will go in catalog folder in root. If you have to find the file in admin panel, you will check inside admin folder in root.

So `http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=common/home` is basically CATALOG FOLDER / common folder / home.php / function index().

If we have to search something in admin lets say `http://demo.opencart.com/admin/index.php?route=catalog/category/add&token=43d61e31aa46a1e66b4bfe63181ebe85` so it is basically ADMIN FOLDER / catalog folder / category.php / function add().

Now if you go through the function, there will be a line at the end something like this.

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/dashboard.tpl', $data));
```

This is your tpl file. Go inside the views folder, templates, common, dashboard tpl. This is your desired file.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I am using Google Inspect Element to try to develop the look of my homepage - which is showing me the html & bootstraps of the homepage, but I cannot find any html for my OpenCart store in my CPanel file manager to alter code - I just see mostly php and tpl files.  How can I directly locate the same html file in CPanel that I am able to view and editing with Google Inspect Element?  I would appreciate your advice!  Thanks again.

Comment: The tpl files are basically your html files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but sometimes it's harder to find what you are looking for in OpenCart.

I have been searching for someting for more than an hour. As it turns out, what I was looking for (PHP CODE), was written in DataBase for whatever reason in this `oc_modification` table as an XML-ish text.

So if you are having trouble finding some file, it actually might not be a file at all. Actual code snippet could be in DB.

I use opencart 3.x.

Easiest way to find something is by downloading whole project, opening it in notepad++ and using "Find in Files" tab. If you can't find it there, there is a big chance you find it in DB.

Open PhpMyadmin, go to current database for your project, press `SEARCH` button on top, put wildcard like '%YOURTEXT%', make sure to select "ALL TABLES" and click `GO`.